# How would I store these values using the Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-api

My project involves running a KS test and a Shaprio Wilks test on a data set. As of now, I am pulling data from a Google Sheets API and performing the stats tests. However, I wanted to know how I could insert data that was already stored as a variable into columns in the google sheets. I hope that wording as ok but here is my code

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import  ServiceAccountCredentials
import re


np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
def estimate_cdf (col,bins=10,):
    print (col)
    # 'col'
    # 'bins'

    hist, edges = np.histogram(col)
    csum = np.cumsum(hist)



    return csum/csum[-1], edges
    print (csum)



scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("ramp").sheet1  # Opens the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()


row = sheet.row_values(3)  # Grab a specific row




number_regex = r'^-?\d+\.?\d*$'





col = sheet.col_values(3)  # Get a specific column print (col)

lol = sheet.col_values(7)
dolphin= estimate_cdf(adjusted := [float(i) for i in col if re.match(i, number_regex)], len(adjusted))



print(col)
print(lol)




yawning =stats.shapiro(col)
print(yawning)



cool= sheet.update_cell(5,6,col)
print(cool)

thelight= sheet.update_cell(5,6,col)
print(thelight)

cool =stats.ks_2samp(col, lol, alternative='two-sided', mode='auto')
print(cool)
```

The Problem lies in THELIGHT variable. I basically try to print the variable col, which is a bunch of different stored numbers, in the Google Sheets.  However, I get this error

```
    C:\Users\james\PycharmProjectsfreshproj\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjectsfreshproj/shapiro wilks.py"
[]
['0.83', '-0.9', '0.56', '0.04', '1.01', '0.58', '-2.63', '-0.36', '-1.09', '0.6', '-0.37', '-1.59', '-2.08', '-1.4', '0.38', '-2.5', '0.06', '-0.69', '-0.32', '-0.87', '-1.14', '0.44', '-0.04', '1.85', '0.11', '-1.64', '0.27', '-1.24', '0.08', '0.46', '0.14', '-0.16', '-1.35', '-0.14', '-0.51', '1.17', '0.98', '-0.82', '0.4', '0.28', '0.4', '-2.03', '0.28', '0.54', '-0.92', '0.53', '-1.93', '-1.92', '-0.35', '-0.02', '0.82', '1', '1.28', '-0.5', '1.13', '-0.43', '-0.27', '-0.13', '-0.32', '-0.47', '-0.17', '1.68', '1.53', '-0.55', '1.65', '-1.1', '-0.16', '1.26', '-0.83', '0.96', '0.15', '-0.41', '0.45', '-0.54', '-2.05', '0.17', '0.75', '0.91', '-0.2', '0.03', '-0.2', '-1.01', '1.67', '-0.73', '0.22', '2.03', '-0.09', '0.28', '-0.46', '-1.16', '0.94', '-0.54', '0.11', '0.77', '0.01', '-0.82', '-1.11', '-0.53', '-0.46', '1.45', '-1.35', '-1.7', '-2.41', '0.78', '-1.6', '1.62', '-1.02', '-0.24', '1.14', '2.09', '1.32', '0.58', '0.57', '0.9', '0.82', '0.68', '-0.73', '0.69', '1.36', '-0.98', '-0.03', '0.2', '-1.5', '1.26', '-0.48', '-0.57', '-0.69', '-0.83', '1.28', '-0.52', '0.02', '0.13', '0.96', '-0.71', '0.55', '0.27', '0.29', '-0.3', '-0.73', '-1.35', '-0.26', '-0.54', '-1.13', '1.08', '-1.78', '-0.42', '-0.58', '-0.13', '3.02', '-0.29', '1.12', '-0.77', '0.13', '-0.32', '-0.96', '-0.21', '-1.63', '0.05', '-1.23', '-0.43', '-1.96', '0.76', '0.92', '-0.51', '-0.66', '0.8', '-0.97', '0.04', '1.75', '-0.44', '-0.41', '-0.16', '1.24', '1.13', '-0.7', '1.15', '0.99', '-1.26', '0.64', '-1.35', '-0.9', '1.13', '-1.31', '-0.03', '-0.48', '-1.94', '0.41', '0.24', '-2.79', '-0.28', '-0.01', '-0.61', '0.51', '1.78', '0.55', '-1.39', '1.6', '0.53', '-1.22', '-0.3', '-1.8', '-0.1', '0.95', '0.09', '-0.11', '-1.55', '1.12', '0.38', '-0.61', '0.16', '-0.42', '0.25', '0.4', '-1.95', '-0.41', '0.18', '-0.47', '0.61', '-0.17', '-0.33', '0.97', '2', '0.19', '0.35', '0.22', '-0.68', '1.43', '-0.69', '0.33', '0.48', '-1.16', '0.14', '1.72', '-0.69', '0.77', '0.49', '-1.66', '-0.69', '-1.05', '0.66', '0.3', '1', '1.2', '1.07', '-1.21', '-1.26', '-0.43', '-0.34', '0.32', '-0.17', '0.66', '0.59', '-1.64', '-1.38', '-0.66', '-2.94', '0.33', '-0.3', '-1.54', '2.45', '-0.33', '-2.15', '-0.36', '1.2', '0.62', '1.12', '-0.73', '1.06', '-0.17', '-0.63', '0.9', '1.26', '0.17', '1.34', '-2.55', '-0.38', '-0.08', '2.74', '0.87', '0.04', '-0.41', '0.1', '0.77', '0.74', '0.56', '0.5', '-0.04', '-0.69', '1.24', '0.31', '-1.21', '-0.5', '2.28', '0.29', '0.01', '-1.02', '-0.11', '-0.36', '0.04', '-0.19', '-0.8', '2.3', '-0.23', '-0.04', '0.31', '-0.4', '1.28', '1.36', '-1.14', '0.18', '0.24', '0.81', '-0.17', '0.99', '0.65', '-0.65', '-0.24', '-0.39', '-0.84', '-1.11', '0.69', '-0.4', '-1.02', '-1.12', '-1.09', '-0.13', '-0.65', '-0.11', '1.12', '-1.67', '-0.29', '0.26', '0.41', '-0.23', '1.02', '-0.93', '0.6', '-0.4', '0.67', '-0.96', '0.61', '-1.13', '2.94', '0.32', '-0.44', '0.12', '-0.41', '0.92', '-0.26', '-1.18', '0.77', '0.07', '1.07', '-0.47', '0.23', '0.82', '-0.89', '-0.33', '1.76', '-0.08', '-1.09', '1.3', '1.17', '0.24', '-1.26', '-1.28', '-0.2', '1.01', '-0.16', '-1.6', '-0.36', '0.41', '1.37', '-0.53', '1.44', '-0.17', '2.13', '0.34', '-0.03', '-0.68', '0.46', '0.41', '-1.7', '-1.25', '0.66', '-0.2', '0.05', '0.13', '-0.96', '0.31', '-0.85', '0.5', '-1.17', '-1.2', '-2.19', '1.52', '1.11', '1.14', '0.43', '-1.38', '-0.76', '0.31', '0.66', '-0.93', '-0.15', '0.76', '-2.05', '-0.5', '0.44', '0.63', '-0.08', '0.19', '-0.41', '-0.46', '0.87', '-1.46', '-0.74', '0.34', '1.48', '-0.2', '1.16', '-0.1', '-1.37', '0.35', '-0.79', '-0.37', '0.69', '-0.68', '-1.58', '-0.7', '0.44', '0.48', '-0.74', '-2.1', '-0.93', '-0.59', '-0.71', '1.28', '1.95', '0.65', '0.8', '0.05', '1.03', '-0.09', '0.71', '-1.51', '0.67', '-0.09', '1.41', '-0.46', '1.01', '1.21', '0.63', '1.08', '-1.04', '0.51', '-0.1', '-1.83', '-1.03', '0.73', '-1.7', '0.4', '1.2', '-0.58', '0.84', '0.15', '-0.61', '-1.48', '-0.53', '1.05', '-0.28', '-0.48', '-2.22', '0.45', '1.79', '1.59', '-1.03', '-0.05', '-0.97', '-0.97', '-0.59', '0.19', '-0.59', '-0.91', '0.03', '-1.17', '0.13', '-0.56', '-0.54', '0.46', '1.79', '-1', '0', '-0.95', '-0.76', '1.04', '0.44', '0.66', '0.05', '-0.81', '-0.49', '-1.33', '-0.84', '-0.26', '0.34', '0.26', '-0.53', '0.78', '-0.73', '0.13', '0.29', '0.62', '0.02', '1.62', '-0.37', '-0.71', '-0.06', '-1.97', '-0.27', '-0.79', '-0.47', '-1.07', '-1.31', '0.05', '0.23', '-1.55', '1.68', '0.82', '0.32', '-0.58', '-0.16', '-0.26', '-0.59', '0.8', '1.12', '-0.68', '0.21', '-0.42', '1.54', '0.68', '2.23', '1.06', '1.29', '0.36', '1.15', '-2.21', '0.05', '0.3', '0.74', '-1.6', '-0.42', '0.76', '0.6', '1.36', '-0.5', '0.82', '-1.22', '-0.4', '0.04', '1.07', '0.86', '0.44', '0.04', '-0.5', '-0.76', '-1.5', '-2.73', '-1.18', '-1.18', '1.82', '0.06', '0.13', '0.96', '-1.15', '0.01', '0.61', '-0.41', '-0.53', '1.17', '-0.34', '-1.18', '0.48', '-0.39', '-1.32', '0.24', '-2.34', '0.12', '0.9', '-1.68', '2.09', '0.87', '0.17', '-0.07', '1.32', '-0.03', '0.28', '-0.47', '-0.17', '-1.1', '0.34', '-0.88', '-0.1', '0.99', '0.15', '0.22', '0.6', '-2', '-0.64', '-2.36', '2.45', '0.23', '0.01', '0.49', '1.4', '-0.56', '-1.82', '0.3', '-0.52', '-0.09', '0.19', '-0.47', '0.15', '0.15', '0.07', '1.61', '0.63', '0.04', '0.56', '-1.97', '-0.27', '-1.6', '0.64', '-0.13', '0.73', '1.27', '-1.94', '-0.1', '2.15', '0.75', '-0.79', '-0.77', '-1.53', '0', '-0.25', '-1.21', '-0.83', '-0.07', '-1.76', '0.55', '-1.75', '1.47', '0', '-0.31', '-0.59', '-0.02', '1.18', '-1.42', '0.8', '1.39', '-1.08', '-1.16', '1.5', '-0.93', '0.85', '1.01', '0.53', '0.26', '0.33', '1.79', '0.4', '1.24', '-0.52', '-1.05', '1.22', '0.34', '-1.07', '-0.84', '-1.37', '-1.25', '1.42', '-0.89', '-1.22', '0.45', '-1.55', '-0.6', '0.95', '0.22', '1.17', '0.61', '-0.43', '-0.2', '0.13', '-0.12', '0.94', '-0.01', '0.85', '0.8', '0.68', '-1.95', '0.23', '-0.53', '-0.42', '0.78', '2.58', '-0.34', '0.02', '1.7', '1.16', '-2.2', '1', '0.51', '0.34', '-1.86', '-0.36', '0.2', '-0.24', '-0.16', '-0.77', '0.35', '1.07', '1.86', '-0.29', '1.06', '0.69', '-1.23', '0.5', '-0.55', '1.07', '-1', '0.18', '0.01', '0.2', '-0.71', '0.74', '1.35', '-0.14', '1', '0.69', '2.47', '-0.34', '-0.25', '0.79', '1.06', '-1.55', '0.03', '-2.05', '1.35', '-0.25', '1.3', '0.11', '-1.51', '-1', '-1.54', '0.53', '-0.67', '-1.77', '-1.04', '-0.75', '-1.53', '-0.19', '-1.03', '-0.48', '-0.92', '1.27', '-0.07', '-1.08', '-0.11', '1.41', '-0.06', '-0.57', '0.1', '-0.16', '0.08', '-0.04', '-1.1', '-0.3', '1.57', '0.54', '-0.67', '0.71', '-0.23', '1.85', '0.08', '-1.97', '-1.01', '-0.39', '0.27', '-0.59', '-0.36', '-0.19', '-0.26', '-0.57', '0.32', '-0.21', '-0.21', '-2.09', '0.17', '-1.18', '-0.5', '-0.76', '0.04', '1.02', '0.64', '0.3', '-0.84', '1.18', '0.21', '1.62', '0.07', '-0.1', '0.63', '0.41', '-0.92', '1.72', '-0.15', '-0.12', '-0.19', '0.64', '-0.27', '0.36', '-0.71', '0.26', '-0.42', '-0.78', '-1.01', '-0.43', '0.16', '-1.73', '-0.7', '0.53', '1.25', '-1.06', '1.63', '0.39', '-0.54', '0.95', '-0.69', '1.36', '1.36', '0.41', '1.15', '-1.18', '0.93', '-0.46', '-0.08', '0.12', '-0.45', '-1.2', '0.32', '-1.25', '0.54', '0.8', '1.25', '2.08', '0.77', '1.92', '0.07', '-0.5', '-1.35', '-0.73', '-0.34', '0.48', '-1.11', '0.11', '-0.42', '0.9', '2.11', '1', '-0.92', '-0.7', '-0.11', '0.26', '0.28', '1.09', '0.18', '0.12', '2.39', '0.1', '1.57', '0.38', '1.25', '-0.05', '-0.74', '0.86', '-0.79', '-0.59', '1.22', '-0.3', '-0.55', '1.13', '-0.93', '-0.57', '-0.53', '0.85', '0.49', '0.36', '1.5', '1.05', '0.7', '0.79', '-0.63', '-0.53', '0.92', '0.84', '-0.99', '0.19', '0.47', '0.83', '0.3', '1.14', '-0.15', '0.51', '-0.61', '0.38', '0.4', '1.38', '1.66', '0.98', '1.51', '-0.02', '0.68', '0.84', '1.68', '-2.48', '0.2', '-0.45', '1.13', '0.51', '1.57', '-0.15', '1.39', '2.94', '1.16', '0.35', '1.5', '1.09', '1.59', '0.94', '0.33', '-1.06', '1.51', '-0.27', '-0.04', '-0.46', '-1.88', '0.73', '0.16', '0.49', '-0.01', '0.58', '-1.08', '0.59', '0.88', '0.29', '-1.88', '-1.79', '-2.33', '2.17', '0.99', '-0.96', '-2.08', '0.03', '-0.21', '1.07', '2.25', '1.03', '-0.98', '-1.96', '0.11', '-1.19', '-0.6', '0.32', '-0.05', '-0.33', '-2', '1.06', '0.21', '0.88', '-1.04', '-0.41', '0.96', '1.45', '0.24', '1.61', '-0.47', '-0.51', '-2.14', '0.42', '-0.06', '-0.75', '0.64', '-0.29', '-0.98', '-1.83', '0.07', '-0.85', '0.05', '0.95', '0.28', '0.19', '0.25', '-0.17', '0.41', '0.01', '-2.23', '-1.43', '-0.45', '-0.51', '-0.38', '0.21', '-0.02', '0.49', '-0.09', '1.19', '-0.95', '0.07', '1.9', '0.33', '0.05', '-0.5', '0.4', '-0.98', '-0.41', '0.75', '1.01', '-0.67', '0.34', '0.59', '-0.42', '0.46', '0.64', '0.42', '-1.07', '0.06', '-0.63', '0.83', '1.28', '-1.64', '-1.42', '0.44', '-0.11', '-0.66', '1.52', '-1.13', '-0.85', '-0.79', '2.1', '-0.99', '0.43', '-0.1', '-0.39', '-0.82', '0.48', '-1.34', '-0.26', '0.41', '1.33', '0.75', '0.23', '-0.38', '0.82', '-1.2', '0.49', '-1.05', '-0.85', '0.9', '-0.53', '-1.66', '0.27', '-0.15', '0.68', '-1.3', '-1.32', '-0.4', '-0.78', '-0.06', '-0.84', '0.9', '0.7', '0.39', '-0.55', '0.56', '-0.01', '0.05', '1.08', '-0.2', '-0.77', '-0.35', '0.52', '0.43', '-1.8', '0.66', '2.09', '-1.13', '-0.59', '-0.52', '0.52', '0.04', '-0.03', '-2.26', '-0.34', '0.02', '-0.24', '0.17', '0.97', '0.45', '-0.69', '-0.82', '-1.13', '0.32', '-0.27', '1.12', '0.63', '0.19', '0.26', '-0.55', '0.27', '0.24', '0.87', '1.88', '1.21', '0.83', '1.33', '-1.16', '-0.28', '2.91', '-0.24', '-0.09', '-1.24', '-1.22', '0.46', '0.82', '0.44', '0.89', '-0.03', '0.08', '-2.23', '0.62', '1.31', '1.33', '-1.15', '-1.97', '-0.19', '-0.93', '-0.75', '-1.01', '-1.38', '-0.04', '-0.85', '0.5', '-1.29', '0.19', '0.51', '1.02', '0.9', '0.15', '1.02', '0.49', '1.62', '1.24', '-0.73', '1.1', '-0.42', '-0.73', '0.48', '0.81', '-0.86', '0.36', '0.05', '-2.04', '-0.2', '0.92', '-0.14', '0.83', '0.44', '-0.05', '1.34', '1.23', '1.49', '-0.07', '0.65', '0.64', '-1.86', '0.5', '0.21', '-0.67', '0.62', '0.53', '-0.05', '0.3', '-0.43', '0.4', '1.47', '0.15', '1.05', '-0.66', '2.62', '0.85', '-0.34', '-0.12', '-0.01', '-0.08', '1.99', '0.16', '-0.92', '-0.59', '1.32', '0.14', '-0.27', '1.68', '0.06', '2.36', '-1.57', '0.12', '-1.49', '-0.64', '1.46', '0.75', '-1.03', '-0.15', '0.1', '2.46', '1.14', '-0.1', '0.38', '-0.22', '-0.99', '0.35', '0.73', '0.65', '0.18', '-1.24', '-0.7', '-0.98', '-1.86', '0.2', '-1.81', '0.18', '0.74', '-0.66', '-0.18', '0.03', '-0.76', '1.97', '-1.56', '0.33', '1.47', '-0.04', '0.25', '0.96', '0.34', '-0.71', '-1.16', '-0.87', '1.78', '0', '0.03', '1.83', '0.32', '0.96', '-0.94', '-1.49', '-0.37', '0.17', '-0.89', '0.53', '-1.81', '-0.94', '0.26', '-0.18', '-0.77', '-1.12', '1.5', '-0.34', '-1.15', '2.41', '0.99', '1.65', '-0.08', '-1.35', '1.36', '0.35', '0.37', '2.81', '0.74', '0.42', '0.11', '1.68', '-1.26', '2.8', '1.87', '1.61', '2.39', '-0.75', '0.25', '-1.71', '-2.73', '0.29', '-0.77', '-0.57', '-0.41', '1.29', '1.56', '-0.83', '-0.73', '-1.77', '0.56', '1.3', '0.09', '-1.4', '1.72', '0.63', '0.73', '-0.77', '-0.45', '-0.35', '-1.36', '0.18', '0.38', '-1.79', '-0.58', '-1.44', '0.82', '1.47', '0.03', '-0.72', '3.21', '-0.76', '1.33', '0.35', '-0.74', '-0.45', '0.61', '0.45', '0.65', '0.79', '-0.42', '-1.47', '1.25', '0.43', '0.02', '1.82', '-2.06', '0.14', '1.25', '0.27', '0.58', '-0.58', '-0.12', '-1.1', '0.7', '-0.21', '-0.44', '0.39', '0.21', '0.51', '-1.29', '0.33', '-0.55', '-1.65', '1.08', '0.85', '-1.46', '-0.82', '-0.61', '-2.37', '-0.72', '-0.35', '-0.09', '1.47', '0.26', '0.43', '-1.52', '-0.38', '1.1', '0.1', '1.62', '0.83', '-2.23', '-0.41', '0.14', '0.63', '-1.05', '-0.01', '0.36', '-1.51', '-0.09', '-0.19', '0.36', '-0.5', '-0.37', '0.65', '0.67', '-2.47', '0.36', '-0.87', '0.72', '-1.36', '-0.85', '1.78', '0.81', '1.07', '1.86', '0.07', '0.28', '1.23', '-0.71', '0.49', '-0.57', '1.03', '1.51', '0.18', '-1.43', '0.76', '-0.87', '-0.91', '-1.55', '0.05', '1.06', '-1.61', '-0.26', '-0.4', '0.02', '0.47', '-0.67', '-1.27', '0.96', '-0.43', '1.19', '-2.73', '0.9', '-0.62', '0.02', '-0.69', '2.07', '-0.44', '1.41', '-0.12', '-1.11', '-0.11', '0.95', '-0.26', '0.23', '-0.65', '-1.55', '1.9', '0.72', '1.53', '-0.01', '-1.84', '-0.57', '-0.95', '-0.24', '-0.77', '0.5', '-0.07', '0.53', '-0.73', '-0.28', '-1.42', '-1.2', '1.06', '-0.91', '1.23', '1.8', '-0.55', '0.64', '1.02', '0.95', '-2.06', '-0.8', '0.48', '0.98', '1.28', '0.13', '2.09', '0.27', '0.75', '0.86', '1.27', '-1.77', '0.05', '0.61', '-1.23', '-0.18', '0.36', '1.28', '-0.07', '-0.6', '-0.39', '-0.83', '-0.18', '0.78', '-0.78', '1.61', '0.48', '1.29', '0.42', '-0.11', '0.25', '2.36', '-0.53', '1.17', '2.18', '-0.57', '-0.47', '-0.38', '-1.28', '-1.61', '0.86', '-0.21', '-1.35', '0.57', '0.57', '-0.25', '0.38', '0.64', '-1.39', '0.71', '-0.15', '0.02', '-0.63', '0.78', '1.54', '-0.29', '0.22', '0.04', '0.91', '1.11', '1.23', '1.38', '0.57', '-0.46', '-1.8', '1.45', '0.23', '2.04', '0.45', '0.37', '0.03', '-0.15', '-0.24', '-0.69', '-0.35', '0.29', '0.78', '-1.47', '0.87', '-1.4', '-1.11', '1.53', '1.74', '-0.2', '2.14', '0.31', '0.71', '-0.55', '-0.38', '0.15', '0.52', '-0.46', '0.38', '-0.34', '-2.38', '2.24', '0.23', '-0.18', '-0.66', '1.61', '0.56', '1.74', '-1.91', '1.22', '-0.57', '-0.53', '0.94', '0.49', '-0.01', '-1.98', '0.04', '0.38', '-0.82', '1.03', '-0.23', '0.75', '2.16', '0.49', '-0.26', '-0.48', '-0.11', '-0.12', '0.13', '-0.18', '0.82', '0.43', '0.01', '-0.32', '-0.21', '-0.38', '0.26', '-0.26', '-0.33', '0.4', '0.05', '-1.14', '1.74', '-0.83', '-0.32', '0.06', '1.59', '0.09', '0.28', '0.06', '-0.95', '0.92', '-1.21', '-1.52', '-1.53', '-0.51', '-0.56', '-0.98', '-2.33', '0.28', '-0.28', '0.06', '1.44', '0.64', '1.28', '-0.37', '0.11', '0.23', '-0.34', '-1.38', '-0.37', '0.2', '-0.91', '-1.95', '-0.18', '0.25', '0.01', '-0.48', '-1.35', '-0.56', '0.67', '0.74', '0.46', '0.05', '-0.44', '1.44', '1.19', '-0.5', '0.12', '-0.37', '0.76', '0.1', '0.01', '0.26', '-0.4', '0.62', '2.8', '-0.85', '1.6', '-1.31', '-2.05', '0.11', '0', 2', '0.97', '-0.51', '1.02', '-4.18', '0.47', '-0.53', '-0.2', '-0.28', '-1.77', '-0.57', '1.13', '1.41', '-0.32', '1.47', '0.22', '1.75', '-0.11', '-1.55', '0.21', '0.16', '0.79', '-0.42', '-0.21', '0.16', '-0.1', '1.9', '0.36', '2.33', '-0.98', '-0.08', '0.12', '-1.94', '-0.05', '1.06', '-0.11', '-1.29', '0.29', '0.2', '0.43', '-0.45', '0.15', '0.65', '1.34', '0.28', '-0.18', '-2.72', '-0.14', '-1.48', '-1.23', '0.2', '1.37', '0.12', '0.08', '0.42', '-0.25', '1.38', '0.14', '-0.7', '-0.09', '-0.06', '-1.88', 
ShapiroResult(statistic=0.447202205657959, pvalue=0.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjectsfreshproj/shapiro wilks.py", line 63, in <module>
    cool= sheet.update_cell(5,6,col)
  File "C:\Users\james\PycharmProjectsfreshproj\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 865, in update_cell
    data = self.spreadsheet.values_update(
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjectsfreshproj\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 235, in values_update
    r = self.client.request('put', url, params=params, json=body)
  File "C:\Users\natha\PycharmProjectsfreshproj\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 73, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid values[4][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "0.83"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-0.9"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "0.56"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "0.04"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "1.01"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "0.58"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-2.63"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-0.36"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-1.09"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "0.6"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-0.37"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-1.59"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-2.08"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-1.4"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "0.38"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "-2.5"\n  }\n  values {\n
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of `I wanted to know how I could insert data that was already stored as a variable into columns in the google sheets.` from your script. Can I ask you about the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: By that i meant, lets say the google sheet had the numbers 1,2, and 3.My code would run a KS test on that and then output K=0.3 to the Python interpreter. So my question is how would i store the output of the KS function as a variable?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your question.